# Angular 2 CRUD application - a model driven Form. Can't get the edit to work. I'm using ngModel

Tags: angular

I'm taking an Angular2 course and following along. Doing a CRUD application - a model-driven Form and using a fake api to get, post(add), put(update) and delete users.

Here is the code with just the get, add and edit processes. The get and add processes works fine. (As well as the delete - but that code came after this and works fine too).

The edit process does NOT work and I'm using ngModel in the Form. I look at the network tab and it shows it is NOT doing the PUT. It's as though it does not recognize that the Form has been changed. My validators on the Form work fine.

I click a user in this list to get to the edit Form.

[image]

After changing just the 'name' in the Edit Form and clicking Save.

[image]

The console tabs:

```
It shows the correct 'user id'. 

I show that I am in my user service just before the api call. Here I show 
the user object with the name change. This is the object that will be passed
to the api.

I show I return from the api call. But it shows an empty object - I think
that is what that is.

And every time I hit save button, I get the same 3 lines (I put them there
to debug) repeated. But no PUT shows up in the network tab.
```

[image]

The network tabs:

```
Does not show a PUT - which I would expect. It only shows the original GET.
```

[image]

---

Here's the user-form.component.ts file.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {ControlGroup, Validators, FormBuilder} from 'angular2/common';
import {Router, CanDeactivate, RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import {User} from './user';
import {NameValidators} from './nameValidators';
import {EmailValidator} from './emailValidator';
import {PhoneValidator} from './phoneValidator';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-form',
    templateUrl: 'app/user-form.template.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/styles.css'],
    providers: [UserService]
 })
export class UserFormComponent implements CanDeactivate, OnInit
{
    form: ControlGroup;
    isSaving = false;
    title: string;
    user = new User();

constructor(fb: FormBuilder, 
            private _router: Router, 
            private _userService: UserService, 
            private _RouteParams: RouteParams
           )
{ 
  this.form = fb.group
  (
    {
        name: ['', Validators.compose(
                    [Validators.required
                    ]), NameValidators.shouldBeUnique],
        email: ['', Validators.compose(
                    [Validators.required, 
                     EmailValidator.email
                    ])],                        
        phone: ['', Validators.compose(
                    [Validators.required, 
                     PhoneValidator.phone
                    ])],             
        address: fb.group
        (
            {
            street: ['', Validators.required],
            suite: [''],
            city: ['', Validators.required],
            zipcode: ['', Validators.required]
            }
        )
    }
  )
}

ngOnInit() 
{
   var id = this._RouteParams.get("id");
   this.title = id ? "Edit a User" : "Add a User";

   if (!id)
   {
      // It is an 'add user' Form so just exit.
      return;
   }
   else
   {
      // It is an 'edit user' Form.

      this._userService.getUser(id)
       .subscribe(user => 
                       this.user = user,

                       // Check to see if the user was found on the database.
                       response =>
                       {
                         if (response.status == 404)
                         {
                           this._router.navigate(['NotFound']);
                         }
                       });                         
   }
}    

save() 
{
   var result;

   if (this.form.valid)
   {
      this.isSaving = true;

      if (this.user.id)
      {
         // For testing:
         console.log("before call sent - id: " + this.user.id);

         result = this._userService.updateUser(this.user);

         // For testing:
         console.log("after call returned back: " + JSON.stringify(result));
      }
      else
      {            
         result = this._userService.addUser(this.user);          

         result.subscribe(x =>
         { 
            this._router.navigate(['Users']);
         });
      }
   }
   else
   {
       this.form.setErrors(
       {
         // Setting a key and value.
         invalidSave: true     
       });
   } 
}

routerCanDeactivate(next, previous)
{
    if (this.form.dirty && !this.isSaving)
    {
       return confirm("A user is being processed but not yet saved. Are you sure you want to continue?");
    }
    else
    {
       return true;
    }
}
}
```

---

Here's the user-service.ts file.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserService
{
    private _url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

constructor(private _http: Http)
{
}

getUsers() 
{    
    return this._http.get(this._url)
                     .map(res => res.json());
}

getUser(userId) 
{
    return this._http.get(this.getUserUrl(userId))
                     .map(res => res.json());
}

addUser(user) 
{ 
    return this._http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify(user))
                     .map(res => res.json());
}

updateUser(user) 
{
     // For testing:
    console.log("In the service - before calling the api: " + JSON.stringify(user));

    return this._http.put(this.getUserUrl(user.id), JSON.stringify(user))
                              .map(res => res.json());                            
}  

private getUserUrl(userId) 
{ 
    return this._url + "/" + userId;
}
```

}

---

Here's the user-form-template.html file.

```
<h1>{‌{ title }}</h1>

  <div class="row formpage">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 well">
       <form [ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()">
           <fieldset>
               <legend>
                User
              </legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input 
                    [(ngModel)]="user.name"
                    ngControl="name"
                    id="name" 
                    class="form-control"
                    type="text"
                    #localVarName="ngForm">

                <div *ngIf="localVarName.control.pending">Checking for uniqueness...</div>

                <div *ngIf="localVarName.touched && localVarName.errors">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger name" *ngIf="localVarName.errors.required">
                        Name is required.
                    </div>

                    <div class="alert alert-danger name" *ngIf="localVarName.errors.shouldBeUnique">
                        Name is already taken.
                    </div> 

                    <div class="alert alert-danger name" *ngIf="localVarName.errors.invalidSave">
                        Name is invalid.
                    </div>                          
                </div>    
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input 
                    [(ngModel)]="user.email"
                    ngControl="email"
                    id="email" 
                    class="form-control"
                    type="text"           
                    #localVarEmail="ngForm" >
                <div *ngIf="localVarEmail.touched && localVarEmail.errors">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger email" *ngIf="localVarEmail.errors.required">
                        Email is required.
                    </div>

                    <div class="alert alert-danger email" *ngIf="localVarEmail.errors.emailInvalid">
                        Email is not valid
                    </div>

                    <div class="alert alert-danger email" *ngIf="localVarEmail.errors.invalidSave">
                        Email is invalid.
                    </div>                          
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                <input 
                    [(ngModel)]="user.phone"
                    ngControl="phone"
                    id="phone" 
                    class="form-control"
                    type="text"           
                    #localVarPhone="ngForm" >    
                <div *ngIf="localVarPhone.touched && localVarPhone.errors">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger phone" *ngIf="localVarPhone.errors.required">
                        Phone is required.
                    </div>

                    <div class="alert alert-danger phone" *ngIf="localVarPhone.errors.phoneInvalid">
                        Phone is not valid
                    </div>

                    <div class="alert alert-danger phone" *ngIf="localVarPhone.errors.invalidSave">
                        Phone is invalid.
                    </div>                          
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset ngControlGroup="address">
            <legend>
                Address
            </legend>

            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="street">Street</label>
                    <input 
                        [(ngModel)]="user.address.street"
                        ngControl="street"
                        id="street" 
                        class="form-control"
                        type="text"           
                        #localVarStreet="ngForm" >
                    <div class="alert alert-danger street" *ngIf="localVarStreet.touched && !localVarStreet.valid">
                        Street is required.
                    </div>            
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="suite">Suite</label>
                    <input 
                        [(ngModel)]="user.address.suite"                    
                        ngControl="suite"
                        id="suite" 
                        class="form-control"
                        type="text"           
                        #localVarSuite="ngForm" >
                    <div class="alert alert-danger suite" *ngIf="localVarSuite.touched && !localVarSuite.valid">
                        Suite is required.
                    </div>            
                </div> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="city">City</label>
                    <input
                        [(ngModel)]="user.address.city"                     
                        ngControl="city"
                        id="city" 
                        class="form-control"
                        type="text"           
                        #localVarCity="ngForm" >
                    <div class="alert alert-danger city" *ngIf="localVarCity.touched && !localVarCity.valid">
                        City is required.
                    </div>            
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
                    <input 
                        [(ngModel)]="user.address.zipcode"
                        ngControl="zipcode"
                        id="zipcode" 
                        class="form-control"
                        type="text"           
                        #localVarZipCode="ngForm" >
                    <div class="alert alert-danger zipcode" *ngIf="localVarZipCode.touched && !localVarZipCode.valid">
                        Zip Code is required.
                    </div>            
                </div>          
            </div>  
        </fieldset>   

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

Here's the user class - user.ts. Used for 2-way binding.

```
export class User
{
   id: number;
   name: string;
   phone: string;
   email: string; 
   // Instantiate the Address class.
   address = new Address();
} 

export class Address 
{
   street: string;
   suite: string;
   city: string;
   zipcode: string;    
}
```

Comment: Are you getting value in id?

Comment: Yes, I see that in my console. In the 1st output line and in the 2nd output line - the user object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In user-service.ts file, add headers

```
 private globalHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
 globalHeaders.append('Content-Type','application/json')
```

modify below request in http put

```
 .put(this.getUserUrl(user.id), JSON.stringify(user), {headers: this.globalHeaders})
```

You need to subscribe the update request as well in user-form.component.ts

```
    this._userService.updateUser(this.user)
                  .subscribe(
                   response => {
                        console.log(response)

                })
            })
```

Except this everything is looking fine.

Comment: When adding the modifiedput..I get: .[ts] Argument of type '{headers: Headers;}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'. Types of property 'headers' are incompatible. Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'Headers'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated. Property 'keys' is missing in type 'Headers'.
(property) headers: Headers

Comment: I was missing the import for Headers.

Comment: That worked...Just wondering why the online course did not include your changes....and it worked in the course as it was being shown online.

Comment: Thanks, Please upvote so that others can also get benefit